# single marker using google map API V3 using Where condition to show single marker from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3

i have two files one `index.php` and another `phpsqlajax_genxml3.php`

Here in file 1 i am getting value through browser `url` and storing that value in `$driver_id` variable.

Now i want to get that value in file 2 when my file 1 control goes to file 2. and using that `$driver_id` value i want to fire a query.

I have copy paste my both files code below, pleasae take a look and please help me if u can solve my problem.

```
file 1 : index.php

<?php
    if(isset($_GET["driver_id"])){
        echo $driver_id = trim($_GET["driver_id"]);
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin-style.css">

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map, infoWindow, intervalId;

        function load() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.489023, 73.814462),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Trigger downloadUrl at an interval
            intervalId = setInterval(triggerDownload, 500);
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function triggerDownload() {

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
            downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data, $driver_id) {

                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("driver");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("mobile_number");
                    /*var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");*/
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lattitude")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));

                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "</b> <br/>" + point;
                    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png");

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon
                    });
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                }
            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

    </script>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" onload="load()">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


file 2 : file 2 is fetching data as xml from database and returning it to index.php

     <?php

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_WARNING);

    // Start XML file, create parent node

    /*if(isset($_GET['driver_id'])) {

        $driver_id = $_GET['driver_id'];

    }*/

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("driver");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    $connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('trackusdown', $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM driver WHERE driver_id='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {

        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        $node = $dom->createElement("driver");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['driver_name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("mobile_number", $row['driver_mobile_number']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lattitude", $row['driver_lattitude']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("longitude", $row['driver_longitude']);
        /*$newnode->setAttribute("driver_id", $driver_id);*/
    }

    echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: `google.maps.MarkerImage` has been deprecated since 2012. You should just do `icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"` when you construct the Marker

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't terribly clear, from the question, exactly what the problem was but I think you were having trouble sending the `driver_id` via ajax to the php script which then queried the database to produce an xml file?

The ajax function and callback looked unusual and have been modified slightly here. I hope this is more or less what you meant to achieve ( though it is not tested )

```
phpsqlajax_genxml3.php
----------------------
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_WARNING );

    /* Is `driver_id` a string or an integer? */
    $driver_id = isset( $_GET['driver_id'] ) && !empty( $_GET['driver_id'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'driver_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : false;

    if( $driver_id ){

        $connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
        if( !$connection ) die( 'Not connected : ' . mysql_error() );

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db('trackusdown', $connection);
        if ( !$db_selected ) die ( 'Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error() );

        /* 
            As you are still using the deprecated mysql_* extensions you 
            need to be ultra careful with the data supplied so should filter
            it as much as needed
        */
        $driver_id=mysql_real_escape_string( strip_tags( $driver_id ) );


        $query = "SELECT * FROM driver WHERE driver_id='{$driver_id}';";
        $result = mysql_query( $query );


        if ( $result ) {

            $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
            $node = $dom->createElement("driver");
            $parnode = $dom->appendChild( $node );

            while( $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
                $node = $dom->createElement("driver");
                $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
                $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['driver_name']);
                $newnode->setAttribute("mobile_number", $row['driver_mobile_number']);
                $newnode->setAttribute("lattitude", $row['driver_lattitude']);
                $newnode->setAttribute("longitude", $row['driver_longitude']);
            }

            header("Content-type: text/xml");
            echo $dom->saveXML();



            mysql_free_result( $result );
            mysql_close( $connection );

            $dom=$node=$result=$connection=null;
            exit();
        }
    }
?>


html page
---------
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin-style.css">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map, infoWindow, intervalId;

            <?php
                /* 
                    could use pure javascript for this instead but this is easy.
                    The driver_id needs to be sent via ajax so make it globally available
                    to make things easier with your functions.
                */
                echo "var driver_id='".trim( $_GET["driver_id"] )."';";
            ?>

            function load() {
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.489023, 73.814462),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                });
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                // Trigger downloadUrl at an interval
                intervalId = setInterval(triggerDownload, 500);/* Every half second? */
            }

            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }



            function triggerDownload() {/* The url has the driver_id parameter set */
                downloadUrl.call( this, 'phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?driver_id='+driver_id, cbdownloadUrl );
            }


            function cbdownloadUrl( response ){/* callback function: do something with the returned XML  */

                var markers = response.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("driver");

                for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("mobile_number");

                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat( markers[i].getAttribute("lattitude") ),
                        parseFloat( markers[i].getAttribute("longitude") )
                    );

                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "</b> <br/>" + point;
                    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage( "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png" );

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon
                    });
                    bindInfoWindow( marker, map, infoWindow, html );
                }
            }

            function downloadUrl( url, callback ) {/* Ajax request to fetch xml */
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if( request.readyState==4 && request.status == 200 ) {
                        callback( request.responseXML );
                    }
                };
                request.open('GET', url, true);
                request.send( null );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" onload="load()">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey RamRaider thanks for the help but it didn't worked.  ..... and i am getting value of driver id on html page and just want to pass it on to phpsqlajax_genxml3.php and run query there with that value as parameter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your original html you are echoing the `driver_id` BEFORE any html - thus making it invalid. In the edit I did the `driver_id` is assigned as a javascript variable and is sent by the ajax function to the php script - is this NOT what you intend?

Comment: I have tested the ajax side of this now by sending to a dummy php file and it does send the request, with the driver_id so I'm not sure where the problem is

Comment: Incidentally - why use xml and not json for this? Also, `latitude` rather than `lattitude`

Answer (score 1):

use SESSION to set value on index.php as

```
if(isset($_GET["driver_id"])){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['driver_id']=trim($_GET["driver_id"]);
    $_SESSION['order_id']=trim($_GET["order_id"]);
```

and get that values on phpsqlajax_genxml3.php using SESSION as

```
$driver_id = $_SESSION['driver_id'];
```